# How to find the stationary points of $f(x,y)=\cos x \cos y$ for all real numbers?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

When solving $f(x,y)=\cos x \cos y$ for its critical points, I am not sure how to handle all the values for any integer multiple of pi $\pi 
n$ and pi ($2\pi n + \pi$), and even after this, I am not sure how I would be able to classify the points (max, min, saddle) in accordance with the parity of $n$.

Comment: Can you at least show us your error?

Comment: Sorry Alex, I've updated the question. It's not an error, rather I'm not sure how to correctly handle the variables when finding the stationary points.

Comment: Are you familiar with second-derivative tests of stationary points?

Answer (score 0):

The conditions $f'_x(a,b)=f'_y(a,b)=0$
give

$$a=n\pi \;,\; b=m\pi $$
or
$$a=\frac {\pi}{2}+n\pi \; ,\; b=\frac {\pi}{2}+m\pi $$

$m,n\in\mathbb Z $.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’ve already determined that there are two sets of critical points: those of the form $(m\pi,n\pi)$ and those of the form $\left(\frac\pi2+m\pi,\frac\pi2+n\pi\right)$, both with $m,n\in\mathbb Z$.

The first set is easily disposed of: $f(m\pi,n\pi)=\pm1$, but these are the absolute max/min values of $f$, so these points must also be local maxima/minima as well. There’s no other possibility because all of the critical points are isolated.

As for the other set of critical points, it’s obvious from the graph of this function that they’re saddle points, but we should show this rigorously. The graph suggests that looking at the behavior of the function along lines parallel to $x=y$ and $x=-y$ near these points is instructive. Near the point $\left(\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$, for $\epsilon\ne0$ We have $\cos(\frac\pi2+\epsilon)\cos(\frac\pi2+\epsilon)=\sin^2t\gt0$ and $\cos\left(\frac\pi2+\epsilon\right)\cos\left(\frac\pi2-\epsilon\right)=-\sin^2\epsilon\lt0$. That is, as we move away from this point $f$ increases in both directions along one line and decreases in both direction along another, so we have a saddle point. The situation is the same at all other critical points in this set, albeit with the signs reversed when $m+n$ is odd.

Alternatively, just as we examine the second derivative of single-variable functions to determine the behavior at critical points, we can consult the function’s *Hessian matrix*, which is the matrix of all of the second-order partial derivatives. For this function $$H(x,y)=\left[\begin{array}{rr}-\cos x\cos y & \sin x\sin y\\ \sin x\sin y & -\cos x\cos y \end{array}\right].$$ If this matrix is positive-definite, we have an isolated local minimum, if negative definite, a maximum. If the matrix is nonsingular and has both positive and negative eigenvalues, then the critical point is a saddle point. $\det H\left(\pm\frac\pi2,\pm\frac\pi2\right)=-1$, which means that one eigenvalue is positive and one negative, so these are saddle points, consistent with what we found above.

Since $H$ is symmetric in $x$ and $y$, we only need to check $H(0,0)$ and $H(\pi,0)$ to determine the nature of the rest of the critical points. $$H(0,0)=\left[\begin{array}{rr}-1 & 0\\ 0 & -1 \end{array}\right]$$ which is obviously negative-definite—a local maximum—and $$H(\pi,0)=\left[\begin{array}{rr}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$ which is positive definite—a local minimum.